# AutoMod command is not sending anything

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm trying to make a AutoMod system for my discord bot and when I type the whitelisted words it doesn't delete and send the message.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_whitelist(message):

    guild: discord.Guild = message.guild
    data = Data.server_data[str(guild.id)]

    if data["active"] == True:
        if data["urls"] in message.content:
            await message.delete()
            await ctx.send(f"{message.author} the URL is in the server's AutoMod whitelist. Please do not use it next time.")

        if data["words"] in message.content:
            await message.delete()
            await ctx.send(f"{message.author} the word is in the server's AutoMod whitelist. Please do not use it next time.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you want to filter words in your server.
For that we use an [on_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message) event.

Your `ctx.send` argument will not work since it is a `bot.event` and `ctx` is not defined.

***Instead you could go for the following:***

```py
import re

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return # Do not check the bots messages
    else:
        if re.match(".*Word1*|.*Word2*", message.content): # Input the words you want to filter
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send(
                f"{message.author.mention} {message.content} was deleted [...]") # Sends the error message into the channel where the word was filtered.
```

You can't send a DM to the user in this case.

Comment: Is it possible for the words to be saved into a Json file.

Comment: That could be possible but I would open another question for that. Share your code/approaches and you will get more help.